# Fortran Debugging

Tags: debugging, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to create a Navier Stokes solver with a bunch of subroutines and multiple iterations which also uses some LAPACK subroutines on MAC through the 
accelerate Framework.

The program compiles correctly on the first iteration but collapses somewhere in the middle saying this:

```
a.out(28015,0x7fff74e78300) malloc: *** error for object 
0x7f81e902a008: incorrect checksum for freed object - 
object was probably modified after being freed.
 *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I am looking for some advice on how to try and debug this. A simpler version of the program runs smoothly but when I try to add the following subroutine to modify
a variable I get the error. I am reproducing the subroutine here too. The subroutine modifies ui and vi variables:

```
   subroutine interpforce(ui,vi,ub,vb,
 1       xb,yb,x,y,m,n,uz,h,dt)
   implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
   integer uz,k,q,IPIV,INFO
   dimension ub(0:uz-1),vb(0:uz-1),xb(0:uz),yb(0:uz)
 1     ,x(-1:m+1),y(-1:n+1),a(0:uz-1,0:uz-1),
 2      fkx(0:uz-1),fky(0:uz-1),dels(0:uz-1),
 3     bx(0:uz-1),by(0:uz-1),IPIV(uz),
 4     fex(0:m,0:n),fey(0:m,0:n),ui(0:m,0:n),vi(0:m,0:n)

   do i=0,m
       do j=0,m

       fex(i,j)=0.0d0
       fey(i,j)=0.0d0

       enddo
   enddo


   do k=0,uz-1
      fkx(k)=0.0d0
      fky(k)=0.0d0
      dels(k)=sqrt((xb(k+1)-xb(k))**2 +  (yb(k+1)-yb(k))**2)

        do q=0,uz-1
          a(k,q)=0.0d0
        enddo
   enddo

   do k=0,uz-1
       do q=0,uz-1

           do i=0,m
              do j=0,n

              a(k,q)=a(k,q)+(umdirac(x(i)-xb(q),h)*
 1            umdirac(y(j)-yb(q),h)*dels(q)*h*
 2            umdirac(x(i)-xb(k),h)*umdirac(y(j)-yb(k),h))

              enddo
            enddo
         enddo
   enddo



   do k=0,uz-1
       bx(k)=-ub(k)/dt
       by(k)=-vb(k)/dt
   enddo

   call DGESV(uz,1,a,uz,IPIV,bx,uz,INFO)
   call DGESV(uz,1,a,uz,IPIV,by,uz,INFO)

   do k=0,uz-1
       fkx(k)=bx(k)
       fky(k)=by(k)
   enddo

   do i=0,m
     do j=0,n
       do k=0,uz-1
          fex(i,j)=fex(i,j)+fkx(k)*(umdirac(x(i)-xb(k),h))
 1                 *(umdirac(y(j)-yb(k),h))*dels(k)

          fey(i,j)=fey(i,j)+fky(k)*(umdirac(x(i)-xb(k),h))
 1                 *(umdirac(y(j)-yb(k),h)*dels(k))
       enddo
     enddo
   enddo

   do i=0,m
       do j=0,n
          ui(i,j)=ui(i,j)+dt*fex(i,j)
          vi(i,j)=vi(i,j)+dt*fey(i,j)
       enddo
   enddo

   return
   end

c ************************************ UMDIRAC FUNCTION          ***************************************

   function umdirac(x,h)
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)

   if (abs(x).lt.h) then
      umdirac=(h-abs(x))/h**2
   else
      umdirac=0.0d0
   endif

   return
   end
```

Comment: Just a point of style, but if you are 'creating' a solver, e.g. writing new code, please adopt modern best practices. It'll make debugging easier as well.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of error is generally the result of *memory corruption* from a stray write operation.

Assuming you're using `gfortran`, try adding the compiler option `-fcheck=bounds` and running again.

If that doesn't do it, try running your program under `valgrind` to see if it can spot your error.

Comment: Following your advice, I installed valgrind and ran my program under it. The problem is that despite having the statements LFLAGS=gfortran -g and LINK=gfortran -g in my makefile, valgrind isn't giving out line numbers for the memory error. Can you point me somewhere I can get help?

Comment: Post your makefile, the detailed output of `make` and `valgrind`, and maybe we can help you. Probably best as an edit to your original question.